# Class doesn't get applied to element in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, javascript-framework

So I want to apply the class .testcolor to the div when testvalue is true and apply nothing when it's false.

When i add the getClass method to :class it doesn't even get called but it gets called when called from {{ getClass }}.
I tried clearing the cache and even rewrote the entire code and it still doesnt work!
Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vue Test</title>
        <style>
            .testcolor {
                color: red !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" :class="getClass">
            <h1>Test stuff</h1>
            <h2>{{ testvalue }}</h2>
        </div>
        <script type="module">
            import { createApp } from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.19/dist/vue.esm-browser.js";

            createApp({
                data() {
                    return {
                        testvalue: true,
                    };
                },
                methods: {
                    getClass() {
                        console.log("Method 'getClass' called");
                        return this.testvalue ? "testcolor" : "";
                    },
                },
            }).mount("#test");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I figured something out that if I mount the Vue instance on the div element and add the :class="testClass" (from the answer) to the h2 it works!
But when I mount it on the h2 element now it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT based on your comment @martin0300

Firstly, you need to wrap the division in another division whose id must be test. Vue does not consider the container element (div with id `test`) as part of the app and does not process any directives. Left a references below that mentions this.

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app

So please change your markup to something like this for applying the value from getClass method...

```
<div id="test">
    <div :class="getClass()">
        <h1>Test stuff</h1>
        <h2>{{ testvalue }}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

...or this way for using the computed property approach (explained below.)

```
<div id="test">
    <div :class="testClass">
        <h1>Test stuff</h1>
        <h2>{{ testvalue }}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

--

Original message:

`getClass` when defined as a method needs to be called, and the returned value (`"testcolor"`) is set as the value of :class. Note the function call `getClass()` in place of the `getClass` you used.

```
<div id="test" :class="getClass()">
    <h1>Test stuff</h1>
    <h2>{{ testvalue }}</h2>
</div>
```

That said, this is not the preferred way to apply classes conditionally. We prefer a computed property over of a method. A method is invoked on every render, whereas a computed property is recomputed only when the underlying reactive data it depends on changes (in this case the computed property `testClass` depends on the reactive property `testvalue`.

The idiomatic Vue code in your case would be the following. Note that computed properties are not invoked like functions since they are internally implemented using accessor methods / using a JS Proxy (`:class="testClass"` and **NOT** `:class="testClass()"`). I believe this difference between the way methods and computed properties are used is the cause of your confusion.

```
<div id="test" :class="testClass">
    <h1>Test stuff</h1>
    <h2>{{ testvalue }}</h2>
</div>
<script type="module">
    import { createApp } from "https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.19/dist/vue.esm-browser.js";

    createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                testvalue: true,
            };
        },
        computed: {
            testClass() {
                console.log("Recomputed testClass");
                return this.testvalue ? "testcolor" : "";
            },
        },
    }).mount("#test");
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still didn't work and the log message didn't appear in the console! The only thing in the console is a warning about using the development version of Vue.

Comment: I edited the original question and added new information on the bottom. I think it may help.

Comment: I have modified the answer based on your feedback @martin0300